# UDP broadcasting loses more packets than received?

Tags: udp, boost-asio, embedded-linux, broadcast

**Scenario:**
I have a simple program to broadcast a little message over the bcast interface on `p2p-wlan0-0` on Linux. Following is the program.

**Code:**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/system/error_code.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <thread>

boost::asio::io_service ioService;
boost::asio::ip::udp::socket udpSocket = boost::asio::ip::udp::socket(ioService);
boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint  endPoint;

void Prepare() {
    const int port = 36512; // Some port
    const std::string& broadcastIPAddress = "192.168.1.1";

    udpSocket.open(boost::asio::ip::udp::v4());
    udpSocket.set_option(boost::asio::socket_base::reuse_address(true));
    udpSocket.set_option(boost::asio::socket_base::broadcast(true));

    boost::asio::ip::address_v4 address =  boost::asio::ip::address_v4::from_string(broadcastIPAddress);
    boost::asio::ip::address_v4 broadcastAddressV4 = boost::asio::ip::address_v4::broadcast(address,
                                                    boost::asio::ip::address_v4::from_string("255.255.255.0")) ;
    endPoint = boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint(broadcastAddressV4, port);
    boost::asio::ip::address interfaceIPAddress(boost::asio::ip::address_v4::from_string(broadcastIPAddress));
    boost::system::error_code ec;
    udpSocket.set_option(boost::asio::ip::multicast::outbound_interface(interfaceIPAddress.to_v4()), ec);
    if (ec) {
        throw std::runtime_error(ec.message());
    }
}

void Broadcast(const std::string& messageToBroadcast) {
    boost::system::error_code ec;
    udpSocket.send_to(boost::asio::buffer(messageToBroadcast.c_str(), messageToBroadcast.length()), endPoint, 0, ec);
    if (ec) {
        throw std::runtime_error(ec.message());
    }
    std::cout << "Broadcasted udp message " << messageToBroadcast << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << "Program starts" << std::endl;
    std::atomic<bool> stopped{false};
    std::thread t([&stopped](){
        std::cout << "Broadcasting thread starting up" << std::endl;
        Prepare();
        do {
            Broadcast("hello");
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
        } while(!stopped.load());
    });

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::minutes(1));
    stopped.store(true);
    t.join();

    std::cout << "Program ends" << std::endl;
}
```

Receiver is a receive loop blindly receiving data. And the whole thing works. I am able to send and receive packets.

**Problem:**
But, I lose a lot of packets over the broadcasting interface. Its like one in a 10 packets is received. I am surprised because its a p2p connection. It takes me 10 broadcasts to get one received on the receiver side. Really strange!
Is this how its supposed to work by the nature of it? Is UDP broadcasting so unreliable? Or am I doing a mistake in the way I have set up the UDP socket?

Comment: The code ignores errors. Do not pass `ec` to turn the errors you don't handle into exceptions.

Comment: I updated the code to not ignore errors. I was ignoring since it is UDP but nevertheless I am pretty sure that none of the calls result in error unless the interface/network really goes down.

Comment: You are printing `"Broadcasted udp message`" even when you didn't.

Comment: Alright. I fixed that print statement as well.

Comment: I raised this question primarily to know if big number of packets drop is expected with UDP on a broadcasting interface. Any suggestions or thoughts on that part would be great to know.

Comment: Run a packet sniffer on both the sender and receiver and tell us whether all the packets leave the device as well as arrive at the destination. Also, run your binary under `strace` (linux) and see whether you can't spot anything suspicious.